# Disconnected Probabilities

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

There are **12** workers and we need to create **2 teams** which have same number of worker among them *(i.e. 6 to 6 team).* In addition, each team has **4 shovels** and **2 axes** *(i.e. there are 8 shovels and 4 axes. They are shared by 2 teams).* 
How many different ways teams and items can arrange?

Comment: I did it but i don't know it is true or false. Combination(12,6)=924 is the team number.Combination(6,4)*Combination(2,2)=15 is the number of items shuffling. I said 924*15*15 is it true?

Comment: Are the teams distinct?  I.e., is the first team going to dig in the northern part of the worksite and the second team going to dig in the southern part of the worksite?  Or are we only interested in who is partnered with who and with what tool?

Comment: ıt was my exam question but i remember it is the same job. Does it make difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that the shovels and axes have either red or blue handles.  I.e., there are a total of four blue shovels, 4 red shovels, 2 blue axes and 2 red axes.

Label each worker 1 through 12.

There is a bijection between the permutations of the multiset $\{4\cdot s_r,~ 4\cdot s_b,~ 2\cdot x_r,~ 2\cdot x_b\}$ and each person's team/tool assignment.

For example, $s_b, s_b, s_r, s_r, x_b, x_r, s_b, s_b, s_r, s_r, x_b, x_r$ corresponds to persons 1,2,7, and 8 getting shovels for the blue team, persons 3,4,9,10 getting shovels for the red team, etc.  The number of different combinations is then $\dfrac{12!}{4!4!2!2!} = 207900$

If you are unable to distinguish between the red team and the blue team, then divide by two for symmetry.

An equivalent way of doing this would be breaking it into steps.  Pick who has axes for blue team, pick who has axes for red team, pick who has shovels for blue, pick who has shovels for red, giving you $\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}$ for the same result.

Comment: I did it true also :O Thank you for your help :)